# raspberry pi not booting and green led never flashes

Tags: pi-4, boot-issues

[image]my raspberry pi 4 won't boot,
it seems like there is a missing diode near the  CPU or is it a resistor, I've seen online pictures and there was a part in that place

Is it possible to repair it if there is supposed to be a diode or resistor?[image][image] (under the gpio text there is a set of white solder dots without anything connected to it from the bottom or top)

edit: the missing diode trace is under the gpio text if you read it when the power USB  is pointing toward you

edit2:this raspberry pi4 4GB was working for months and my sd card is very high quality

edit3: new picture showing where the part should be clearly
edit4: here is everything I am using: the official charger, a case, HDMI to micro HDMI, Screen, screen charger

Comment: where do you think the diode should be?

Comment: if you look under the gpio text when the USB c is pointed toward you the should be a diode and it isn't there

Comment: There is a lot of background missing here.  Did this Raspberry Pi 4 ever boot up in the past?  What has changed.  Many many times people use under rated power supplies preventing the Raspberry Pi 4 to boot properly.  The SDCard can be corrupted by not shutting the Raspberry Pi 4 properly.  Have you attempted to re-create the SDCard or replace the SDCard?  It is unlikely a part got knocked off the PCB.  Why do you expect a missing part?  How do you know the part is a diode?  Why not zero ohm option jumper or other 2 pin device?

Comment: st2000 i am sure there is a missing part since there is picture's in the internet that had it and I found a little( but destroyed ) part on my floor and I am using the original charger

Comment: @rami please look at the picture ... your description does not match the picture

Comment: @jsotola i updated the images to be more clear

Comment: that is not `under the gpio text` ... it's to the left of GPIO text

Comment: Do you know how to edit a jpg to draw lines, etc?? That would make things so much more clear.

Comment: @Seamus I just added a new picture that has a circle on the part

Comment: Not the clearest picture, but I just checked my RPi 4B, and I don't see a component soldered in that location - only the two solder dots.

Comment: @Seamus then why isn't it booting, maybe its only there on the new RPI 4 GB?

Comment: Let me Google that for you: [1](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=58151), [2](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=why+doesn%27t+my+Rpi+boot&atb=v278-1&ia=web)